# Nicer proof that $2^{n+2}$ divides $3^m-1$ if and only if $2^{n}$ divides $m$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

(I've accepted Carl's answer because he was first, but robjohn and sirous each gave very nice answers as well.)

---

I'm interested in the highest power of two that divides $3^m-1$ for even $m \geq 2$. In fact, I can show that this is exactly four times the largest power of two dividing $m$. I.e., $2^{n+2}$ divides $3^m-1$ if and only if $2^{n}$ divides $m$ for $n \geq 1$.

But, my proof seems too tedious for such a nice fact. I've written it up below, but since I want a better proof, you might want to just ignore it. (My motivation comes from finite fields, but the question seems interesting regardless.)

---

Suppose that $2^{n+2}$ divides $3^m-1$. The proof proceeds in two steps. First, we show that the result holds when $m$ is itself a power of two. I.e., $2^{n+2}$ divides $3^{2^{n'}}-1$ if and only if $n \leq n'$. Next, we show that for any $m$ such that $3^m-1$ is divisible by $2^{n+2}$, we must have $\gcd(m,2^{n}) = 2^{n}$.

For the first part, we observe the factorization
$$
3^{2^{n'}} - 1 = (3^{2^{n'-1}} +1) (3^{2^{n'-2}} + 1) \cdots (3^2+1)(3+1)(3-1)
\;. 
$$
(This is just the factorization of the $2^{n'}$th cyclotomic polynomial and does not use any properties of the number 3.) Since $3^a + 1 = 2 \bmod 4$ for all even $a$, the largest power of two dividing this is exactly $2^{n'+2}$, as needed. (There are $n'+1$ terms, each even. The only term divisible by $4$ is the term $3+1=4$.)

For the second part, we notice that if $2^{n+2}$ divides $3^m-1$, since $2^{n+2}$ also divides $3^{2^{n}} - 1$, $2^{n+2}$ must divide their difference $3^{\min(2^{n},m)}(3^{|m-2^{n}|}-1)$. Since $3^{\min(2^{n},m)}$ is odd, this in turn implies that $3^{|m-2^n|}-1$ is divisible by $2^{n+2}$. We can repeat this procedure many times to simulate the Euclidean algorithm in the exponent, eventually showing that $3^{\gcd(m,2^{n})} - 1 $ is divisible by $2^{n+2}$. Of course, $\gcd(m,2^{n})$ must be a power of two, and therefore the previous argument implies that it $\gcd(m,2^{n}) = 2^{n}$, as needed.

Comment: Doesn't $2^3|3^2-1$ but $2^2\nmid 2$? I think you want that $2^n|3^m-1$ iff $2^{n-2}|m$, right? (for $n\geq 2$, of course)

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Thanks! (In my application it's natural to consider $2m$, which had me confused.) Fixing it now.

Comment: Good stuff. I'm just wondering what motivated the addition of the f.f. tag. You show that the coset of $3$ has the maximal order $2^n$ in the group $\Bbb{Z}_{2^{n+2}}^*$, which is equivalent to showing that $x^{2^{n+1}}+1$ splits into a product of two factors of degree $2^n$ in $\Bbb{F}_3[x]$. In other words that the modulo three factors, $g(x)=x^2-x-1$ and $h(x)=x^2+x-1$, of $x^4+1$ have the property that both $g(x^{2^n})$ and $h(x^{2^n})$ are themselves irreducible. Or what?

Comment: This fails for $m=1$ Since $2^0\mid1$, yet $2^2\nmid3^1-1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Exactly. Equivalently, I'm interested in which finite fields of characteristic 3 have primitive $2^n$th roots of unity.

Comment: @robjohn This is why I require $n \geq 1$. I added that $m$ should be even to make this more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a prime $p$ and positive integer $k$, define $\nu_p(k)$ to be the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $k$. We want to show that

$$\nu_2\left(3^n-1\right)=\begin{cases} 1&\mathrm{\ if\ }k\equiv 1\bmod 2\\ 2+\nu_2(n)&\mathrm{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

We use strong induction to simplify calculations:

If $n$ is odd, then $3^n-1\equiv 2\bmod 4$, so the claim is true. Assume the claim is not true for all even $n$, and consider the smallest such $n=2m$. We have

$$3^{2m}-1=\left(3^m-1\right)\left(3^m+1\right).$$

If $m$ is even, then $\nu_2(3^m-1)=2+\nu_2(m)$ (by our strong inductive hypothesis) and $3^m+1\equiv 2\bmod 4$ so $\nu_2(3^m+1)=1$, which gives

$$\nu_2\left(3^{2m}-1\right)=3+\nu_2(m)$$

as desired. If $m$ is odd then $\nu_2(3^m-1)=1$ and $3^m+1\equiv 4\bmod 8$, so

$$\nu_2\left(3^{2m}-1\right)=1+2=3=2+\nu_2(2m),$$

as desired.

This isn't really different from your argument, it's just a more compact way of phrasing it. Similar results can be proven for any $p>2$; the most general form that looks nice is that if $p$ is an odd prime so that $p|a-b$ while $p\nmid a,b$, then

$$\nu_p\left(a^n-b^n\right)=\nu_p(a-b)+\nu_p(n).$$

(as user236182 mentioned, this is called Lifting the Exponent).

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll probably accept this answer, but I'll leave it open for a bit just in case someone happens to know a really slick proof.

Comment: One small correction, you say, "If $n$ is odd, then $3^k-1\equiv 2\bmod 4$", I think that $k$ and $n$ should be one or the other.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks for noting that - I've corrected my answer.

Comment: (+1) As I noted in a comment to my answer, our answers share a core of induction on the power of two in the exponent, but we chose two equally valid approaches to handle the odd factors in the exponent.

Answer (score 2):

For $k\ge0$ and odd $p$,
$$
3^{p2^k}-1=\left(3^{2^k}-1\right)\overbrace{\left(3^{(p-1)2^k}+3^{(p-2)2^k}+\cdots+1\right)}^\text{$p$ terms}
$$
For $k\ge2$,
$$
3^{2^k}-1=\left(3^{2^{k-1}}-1\right)\overbrace{\left(3^{2^{k-1}}+1\right)}^{2\pmod4}
$$

Comment: Very nice! Thanks! I think this is essentially Carl Schildkraut's proof, but more succinct, right?

Comment: There are elements that are the same, but I'm not sure I would say that they are essentially the same.

Comment: Fair enough. To be clear, I didn't mean that as a criticism. (I'm giving a lecture tomorrow in which this question arises. I wasn't planning on trying to present a proof, but this proof is so succinct that I might present it.)

Comment: The approach in my post is to show that the number of factors of two is unchanged when reducing the exponent by removing odd factors, then show the result on exponents which are a power of two (by induction). In Carl Schildkraut's answer, the result is proven for odd exponents, then the exponent is reduced by powers of two until it is odd. We are both doing induction on the power of two in the exponent, but I think there are essential differences (my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

You can use binomial theorem; we may write:

$3^m-1=(4-1)^m-1$

Now if m is even then $3^m-1=(4-1)^m-1=(2^2)^m+M(m,4)$

Where M(m, 4) mean a polynomial having factors m and 4:

$M(m, 4)= (^m_1) 4^{m-1}(-1)^1 + . . .(^m_{m-1}) 4^1 (-1)^{m-1}=4mk$; $k∈   N$

Now we must have:

$2^{n+2} | 3^m -1$

Or:

$(2^2)(2^n) | (2^2)^m +M(m, 2^2)$

One common divisor of both sides of this relation is $2^2$, since the least power of $4$ on RHS is 1, then the relation can be reduced to:

$2^n | 2^{m-1}+ k m$

$2^n$ divides $2^{m-1}$ if $m-1>n$.Therefore the condition of holding the relation is if and only if  $2^n |C^m_i $ for $i=1$ to $i=m-1$ or $2^n | m$.

Comment: This proof looks really nice, but I don't understand the notation $M(m,4)$ and I'm confused about how you handle all the terms in the binomial expansion  $\binom{m}{i} 4^i$. I guess the idea is that all terms except $i=0$ and $i=1$ are divisible by $8m$, while the $i=1$ term is $4m$ (and the $i=0$ term is subtracted out). So, the full expression is divisible by $4m$ but not $8m$?

Comment: Noah, I mean all terms of $M(m, 4)$ are divisible by $4m$. The mth term is the only term that has the factor $4$ for its power is 1.By reducing, this factor(4) is eliminated and only a multiple of m remains, so only m is common factor in polynomial $M(m, 4)$  on RHS after reducing.